# How do I scale an use'd svg with auto-width?

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design

I have this simple foo.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <symbol id="test" viewBox="0 0 40 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect width="40" height="20" fill="currentColor" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Is is used in this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <style>
    .logo {color:#f0f; border:1px solid #0f0; height:1em; width:auto;}
  </style>
</head><body>
  <svg class="logo">
    <use xlink:href="foo.svg#test" x="0" y="0" />
  </svg>
</body></html>
```

Sadly, if I set the height to 1em, the rect gets rendered as 32x16 but the svg gets rendered to 302x18. Expected would be 34x18. How can I archive this?

Answer (score 1):

The width of 302px is the default width for SVGs of 300px + 2*1px border width. You need to give the SVG element in your HTML both a width and height that fits the aspect ratio of the symbol or give it a viewBox attribute matching the viewBox of the symbol. Here I use the viewBox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .logo {
      color: #f0f;
      border: 1px solid #0f0;
      height: 1em;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 40 20">
    <use xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiID8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8c3ltYm9sIGlkPSJ0ZXN0IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNDAgMjAiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89InhNaW5ZTWluIG1lZXQiPgogICAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjQwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwIiBmaWxsPSJjdXJyZW50Q29sb3IiIC8+CiAgPC9zeW1ib2w+Cjwvc3ZnPg==#test" x="0" y="0" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isnt the viewbox already defined by the symbol? What is the purpose of the symbols viewbox, if i have to state it again in the html's svg?

Comment: @rhavin the use element just acts as any other SVG element, so what happens inside the use/symbol does not affect the outer SVG.